# How can I display the number of free places for an event using google script and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a registration form for an event and I would like that every time the website is loaded, the number of free spots is calculated from a Google Sheet document and the value is displayed on the form, that has been programmed in html/javascript.

This is my Code.gs

```
function updateSpots(){
  var nospots
  var url="<MY URL>";
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws=ss.getSheetByName("2022-2023");
  var range = ws.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  nospots = values.length;
  return nospots;
}
```

My index.html

```
<div>
<p id="places"></p>
<script>
  var booked_spots = updateSpots();
  //var booked_spots = google.script.run.updateSpots(); I tried this before... did not work
  console.log(booked_spots)
  if(booked_spots < 20)
  {
    document.getElementById("places").innerHTML = (20 - booked_spots);
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById("places").innerHTML = "There are no longer places available for this event";
  }
</script>
</div>
```

I get this error on the console:

```
VM295:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: updateSpots is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:22
    at qh (2924413381-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:128:336)
    at 2924413381-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:25:132
    at Ld (2924413381-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:56:477)
    at a (2924413381-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:54:52)
```

And also, on the website the number of free spots do not appear.

I am new to this, so any help is very much appreciated. :)

Comment: So, what doesn't work about your code?

Comment: Hi @Geshode, thanks for the hint. I have just updated the question. Basically I get the error telling me that updateSpots is not defined. But it is defined on code.gs. And where there should be the number of spots, there is basically nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call the server function `updateSpots` you need to do the following.  It is just my personal preference to always use Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions to insure variable are retained in the local scope of the IIFE.  I avoid global variables as much as possible.

```
<script>
  (function () {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
        function(booked_spots) {
          if(booked_spots < 20)  {
            document.getElementById("places").innerHTML = (20 - booked_spots);
          }
          else {
            document.getElementById("places").innerHTML = "There are no longer places available for this event";
          }
        }
      ).updateSpots();
    }
  )();
</script>
```

Reference

- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [IIFE](https://stackabuse.com/javascripts-immediately-invoked-function-expressions/)

Comment: If this answers your question then mark it as the answer so others with similar question can find an answer.